# duplicate pane to show history in tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

Sometimes, the output of a command is very long and thin, and my screen is much wider than it is tall. Is there any way to make a new pane which is a copy the current one, but more scrolled up so that more of the screen could be seen at a time?

For example, say I have a command that prints the alphabet, and this is what it looks like:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|w                                                                             |
|x                                                                             |
|y                                                                             |
|z                                                                             |
|______________________________________________________________________________|
```

I want it to look something like:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|w           |s                |o             |k               |g              |
|x           |t                |p             |l               |h              |
|y           |u                |q             |m               |i              |
|z           |v                |r             |n               |j              |
|____________|_________________|______________|________________|_______________|
```

If the newly spawned panes also be scrolled in parallel with the first, continuously showing the history before it, that would be great as well